# Using moment.js to convert time (HH:mm:ss) to (HH:mm)

Tags: javascript, jquery, momentjs

I was wondering if I could use moment.js to convert an sql TIME (HH:mm:ss) to just HH:mm. Or maybe there is a simple JavaScript/jQuery solution to this?

Comment: Uhhh.. What do you mean a "sql TIME"?  Most SQL databases do *not* store dates or times as strings...

Comment: In PHPMyAdmin I could select TIME as a type... Idk if that is an sql time though

Comment: Yes, that's a `TIME` data type ([docs here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time.html)).  The *formatting* of that type is entirely up to how you retrieve it in your code.  It is not stored as a string in the db.

Comment: timeFormatting = time => {
        return moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')
    }

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can:

```
moment('12:59:01', 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')
```

Or, if the format is consistent, you could just chop the last 3 chars:

```
'12:59:01'.slice(0, -3)
```

Comment: Well, that was easy. Why didn't I find an answer like this on google? :) Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

```
timeFormatting = (time) => {
  return moment(time, 'HH:mm:ss').format('HH:mm')
}
```